# ARKit – Bounding Box

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I need the values of bounding box before placing the object. The bounding box values are `0` if I try to take it before placing the object in scene view. How this can be done?

Or is there any other way to get the width and height of object before placing it. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi @Developer, add your code please.

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, the bounding box is the boundaries of the geometry in your node. It by itself doesn't return the width and height. To calculate the width and height you need to use the *.min* and *.max* atributes from the bounding box.

Exemple:

```
var min = node.boundingBox.min
var max = node.boundingBox.max
let width = CGFloat(max.x - min.x)
let height = CGFloat(max.y - min.y)
```

Comment: The min and max values are 0 before placing the 3d object.

Comment: The min and max values are related to the geometry and not to the node. If its 0 than you probably didn't instantiate the geometry.